# How to use a string in Chinese characters as input for another command in bash?

Tags: bash, python, unicode

I'm currently using a command to convert some Chinese characters into pinyin, which requires the string in my bash to be Unicode safe and put the result in another variable. I can run the following command normally:

```
  chinese="你好"
  to-pinyin.py $chinese
```

It will print the output as expected, however, since I want the output in a variable, I tried to do the following:

```
  chinese="你好"
  pinyin=$(to-pinyin.py $chinese)
```

And python will fail with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/~/to-pinyin.py", line 31, in <module>
    print pinyin.get(hanzi, delimiter=" ").capitalize()
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u01d0' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Same thing will happen with backticks. I think I will work around by writing the output to a file and to a conversion there, then load the strings to a variable. How else can I fix this so that I can avoid the workaround?

EDIT:

Per request here is the output of locale:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

**SOLUTION USED**

Thanks to muru's response and some help of [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492483/setting-the-correct-encoding-when-piping-stdout-in-python) I added `.encode('utf-8')` to the end of the printed strings in my python script.

I wish I could switch to python3, but there is no defalut pinyin package there and I can't seem to install any good pinyin package that would get my job done quickly in python3. I remember trying for a while but python3 kept refusing to import the package I had installed, so I just installed one in python2 and it worked straight out of the box.

Comment: Can you add to your question the output of `locale`?

Comment: @xenoid Here it is.

Comment: Problem is likely in your python code. The message is about reading UTF-8 as ascii. Is it Python2 and Python3? How/where do you handle encodings?

Comment: @xenoid It is python 2.7.12. It can read the input from the terminal correctly, as shown before. The issue arises when changing from output to the terminal to output to a variable. I can't see why python would be the cause. For me bash is converting the input to ascii when I try to get the output in a variable.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't quote it in the terminal? like `to-pinyin.py "$chinese"`

Comment: @Jesse_b I didn't. Should I? It is supposed to do the same, right?

Comment: @GabrielDiego: Yes but it seems like that isn't what causes your issue.  In general though it is always best practice to quote any variable that will be expanded, especially if the variable contains special characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an issue with [Python 2's `print`](https://pythonhosted.org/kitchen/unicode-frustrations.html#frustration-3-inconsistent-treatment-of-output), and reason to favour Python 3's consistent Unicode handling.

> Now why does redirecting to a file cause problems? It’s because
>   [`print()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#print) in python2 is treated specially. Whereas the other file-like
>   objects in python always convert to *[ASCII](https://pythonhosted.org/kitchen/glossary.html#term-ascii)* unless you set them up
>   differently, using [`print()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#print) to output to the terminal will use the
>   user’s locale to convert before sending the output to the terminal.
>   When [`print()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#print) is not outputting to the terminal (being redirected to a
>   file, for instance), [`print()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#print) decides that it doesn’t know what locale
>   to use for that file and so it tries to convert to *[ASCII](https://pythonhosted.org/kitchen/glossary.html#term-ascii)* instead.

Comment: +1: Very interesting. But is there an easy way out of this bind ? E.g. to force interpretation of `print` in Python 2.7.x according to a locale of user's choice, when there is no tty stdout involved but a command expansion as in `var = $(print ...)` ?